# Fixed point of a method

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-points

Is there any way to compute the fixed point of this equation : $xe^{-x} = e^{-3}$.

If it is a quadratic equation then i can use $\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$ but i don't know how can i directly compute a fixed point for such equations.

I need this to compute the convergence factor which is given by $F^\prime(x^\prime)$ where $x^\prime$ is the fixed point.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Could you precise what is your F ? You mean roots ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: Is your fixed point iteration $x_+=F(x)=e^{x-3}$ or $x_+=F(x)=3+\ln x$, or something else? That may decide if there is convergence at all and if it converges to $x=-W_0(-e^{-3})\approx 0.0524690974577\in(0,1)$ or to $x=-W_{-1}(-e^{-3})\approx 4.50524149579\in(1,\infty)$.

Comment: An equation does not have a fixed-point, a function has. You must set your equation in a form $x=f(x)$ and discuss the fixed point(s) of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you rearranged the equation as

$$x=e^{x-3}=:f(x),$$

(magenta curve) you have

$$f'(x')=e^{x'-3}=x'.$$

Now notice that

$$0<e^{0-3}$$ and $$1>e^{1-3}$$ and there must be a root $x'\in(0,1)$. Hence the fixed-point is stable.

Note that there is another solution in $(4,5)$ (as $e<4$ and $e^2>5$), corresponding to divergent iterations.

---

The situation is reversed with $f(x):=\ln x+3$, that yields the same solutions (blue curve), but the stable fixed point in $(4,5)$.

[image]

---

**Additional comment:**

It doesn't make much sense to solve the equation to discuss convergence, as the fixed-point method will most probably be used for the purpose of finding that root. It is more appropriate to determine a gross bracketing.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Lambert function you can rewrite

$$ -(x)e^{-x}=-e^{-3} $$ which is

$$ x=-W_0(-e^{-3}) $$
 or

$$x=-W_{-1}(e^{-3})$$
Hopefully well defined because $-e^{-3} \in [-e^{-1},+\infty[$

Comment: You missed one of the solutions.

Comment: Of course! multivaluated character implies à second solution through the second branch

Comment: There is no reason to drop it.

Comment: Absolutly, I had in mind $e^{-3}$ which only belongs to $W_0$